# Powering gate of 4 V Vth MOSFET with Raspi 0

Tags: voltage, mosfet, raspberry-pi

I am trying to have a Raspi 0 GPIO pin signal to the gate of a MOSFET IRF540n at a certain time. The issue is the GPIO pins give 3.3 V output and the threshold voltage for the MOSFET is 4 V.

I am not in a position to order additional parts, I have access to various resistors and some diodes. Can someone please help me out with making this work?

Some additional info:
I do not have access to any additional power sources, only the 5 V source on the Raspi. Connecting the 5 V directly to the gate achieves the result I need, but I need to trigger these at certain times.

Comment: Then you'll need to arrange about 10V on the gate to switch that MOSFET fully on.

Comment: Best option is to buy another MOSFET which is 3.3 V compatible otherwise you need a boost converter.

Comment: I'm thinking you could use a bootstrap configuration if you have the extra parts. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcQV_ZpK1W8

Answer (score 1):

You seem be be between a rock and a hard place:

- RPI GPIO swing is only between 0 and +3.3V
- IRF540 wants +5V to *fully* turn on.

You might ask, "What is an acceptable voltage (above 0V) to keep the IRF540 off?". The answer is perhaps a few volts. So a kludge circuit  would use a LED to translate the RPI GPIO ranging from (0 to +3.3V) up to (+1.8 to +5V):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHnIO3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You have a choice of using infrared LED, RED LED, Green LED, White LED, in increasing order of added offset voltage. If you don't have a LED, you might try a few (3?) silicon diodes in series.

This is not a robust solution, since threshold voltage varies from device to device. But it may be a simple way to get you out of a tight spot. Be aware that the full range of IRF540 ON/OFF resistance will not be achievable.
I wouldn't try this in a PWM application where M1 should switch on/off quickly.